# Iteration function without using global variables

Tags: javascript

I need a function that:
on first iteration returns 0, on each next iteration returns previous number incremented by 1, e.g 
first iteration - 0 
second iteration - 1
third iteration - 2

but **the catch is** that it doesn't take any arguments and it also **doesn't use any global variables** (or variables outside of that function).

Do you have any idea how to implement it without using any global variables?

Comment: Do you mean *invocation* instead of *iteration*? Loops iterate.

Comment: *"Do you have any idea how to implement it without using any global variables?"* Assuming you mean *invocation* (i.e. `foo(); foo(); foo();`),  as already mentioned using a generator would work, but the caller needs to be able to handler iterators. You can also keep state as a property on the function object itself. I think you have to provide more details. Show us how the function is called.

Comment: Just don't make the variable global. It does need to reside outside of the function though: `var count; { let i=0; count = () => i++; }`. Similarly, you can use an IIFE to the same effect: `var count = (i => () => i++)(0);`

Comment: You could make a generator based on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators ... there's an example of generator on this page btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a closure over the variable and call the returned function.

```js
const fn = (i => () => i++)(0);

console.log(fn());
console.log(fn());
console.log(fn());
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm! Thanks, I didn't know anything about Immediately-invoked functions

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Generator` function to achieve this.

> The function* declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object.
>
> Generators are functions which can be exited and later re-entered. Their context (variable bindings) will be saved across re-entrances.

```js
function* getNumber() {
    let counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        yield counter++;
    }
}
const generator = getNumber();
console.log(generator.next().value);
console.log(generator.next().value);
console.log(generator.next().value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using generator [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
function* increment() {
  let index = 0;
  while (true)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = increment();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to create a function with a permanently set context. In that case, you don't have a "global" variable, since you'd just be using `this` inside the function.

```js
const f = (function iterator() {
  return this.i++;
}).bind({i:0}); //<-- set the conext with an initial value of `i`;

console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by defining a property on function itself

```js
function counter(){
  if(this.count === undefined){
     this.count = -1
  }
  this.count++
  return this.count
}

let count = counter.bind({})

console.log(count())
console.log(count())
console.log(count())
console.log(count())

console.log(this.count)
```

Comment: @Sohail ahh you're right, we can change the this though by using bind :)

Comment: why do we have to use bind tho? Using 'this' keyword' is not fitting the requirements?

Comment: @hurit if i don't bind, then this will refer to global object here

Comment: you could bind the property as well, then you do not need to check for it.